# Sencha Touch - How can I integrate various icons (one for each item) into a selectfield?

Tags: select, icons, touch, extjs, field

In Sencha Touch 2 I use a selectfield component with 5 options. Each has its own icon. On clicking the input field, the icon shows in the select box before the text.
As of now I have to look up the ID of the various option texts in the source code of the running app and then adapt the CSS files, like in

```
#ext-element-150 { 
background: url('../images/water.jpg');
background-size: 40px 40px;
padding-left: 50px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

where ext-element-150 is the (looked-up) ID of one of the options elements.

The result looks like this:
[image: Select list with icons]

But this is an unflexible and error prone workaround rather than a solution. What would be a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Put the images in your itemTpl config on the list.

eg :

```
<div> <img src=/path/to/{imagename}></> <span> {description} </span>
```

Then add the image name to your store backing the list.